# How do I round the edges of a side?

Tags: modeling

Let me start off by saying that I'm very new to blender.

Alright, so I need to know how I would go about rounding off the edge of this model: [image]

(heres a wireframe of that model) [image]

to make it look like this picture: [image]

if you look at the previous picture closely, you can see that the circled area is kind of rounded off. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add a wireframe of your mesh (*e.g.* from the Edit mode)? Are you using any modifiers, like Solidify?

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: Not really related to your question, but keep in mind that mechanical pieces are physically separated in reality. You should do the same for your mesh: this can help both to be more simple and realistic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "*Bevel*" on selected edges.

Select the edges that you want to round, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel them. Scrolling your middle mouse button wheel you can choose the bevel resolution.

[image]

Bevel comes in different "modes" that you can cycle using <kbd>M</kbd> during the tool's operation. Unfortunately neither of these modes can be used to force a predominant axis. For fine adjustments you will need to edit your geometry before or after applying bevel.